# Run multiple find and replaces in Python (on every file in the folder and sub-folder)

Tags: python

I have a folder (courses) with sub-folders and a random number of files. I want to run multiple search and replaces on those random files. Is it possible to do a wild card search for `.html` and have the replaces run on every html file ?

Search and replaces:

1) `"</b>"` to `"</strong>"`

2) `"</a>"` to `"</h>"`

3) `"<p>"` to `"</p>"`

Also all these replaces have to be run on every file in the folder and sub-folders.

Thank you so much

Comment: use `os.walk` to walk through the folder/subfolder looking for `.html` files.  When you find one, you could do your search/replace with a simple `re.sub`, or possibly an even simpler `str.replace`.

Comment: Newbie here An example would be REALLY helpful

Comment: The manual for os.walk does contain an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
import os
from os.path import walk

mydict = {"</b>":"</strong>", "</a>":"</h>", "<p>":"</p>"}

for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk('./'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.html'):
            filepath = os.path.join(path,f)
            s = open(filepath).read()
            for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
                s = s.replace(k, v)
            f = open(filepath, 'w')
            f.write(s)
            f.close()
```

You can change `os.walk('./')` to `os.walk('/anyFolder/')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `glob` module to get a list of `*.html` files.

Comment: could you explain with an example ?

Comment: It seems to me that `glob` will be difficult to recurse into an arbitrarily nested subfolders.  `os.walk` + `os.path.splitext` seems like a better bet.

Comment: Ooops. Forget that answer. Doesn't work for sub folders. @mgilson is right.

Comment: Or combine `os.walk` (to walk all directories) with `glob.glob` (to filter *.html).